# Github website showing up blank when I try to deploy it

Tags: html, css, github

Hi im trying to learn how to use Github to publish a website I coded but everytime I deploy it it shows up blank, this is my repo: https://github.com/bbravoo/bbravoo.github.io- if you can help thanks!

I've tried looking in the pages tab and trying to switch which branch it is deploying from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... What specifically are you asking?  What page in your GitHub deployment are you trying to open and how are you trying to open it?  What specific result are you expecting and why?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer:

Delete your `index.html` and rename your `site.html` to `index.html`.

## Explanation:

You have two `html` files in your repository. One of them seems to be the site that you want to deploy `site.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar">
   <a href="#Home">Home</a>
   <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
   <a href="#Radio">Radio</a>
   <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
 </div>

<section id="Home">
  <p> </p>
  <h1><center>Home</center></h1>
   <img src="IMG_6021.jpg">
   <p> college student studying Music and Math. She is a radio host where she hosts a jazz show. She is interested in web development, data science, marketing, social media, and public relations.</p>
  </section>
<section id="Portfolio">
  <p> </p>
  <h1><center>Portfolio</center></h1>
  <p> </p>
  <IMG SRC="giphy.gif">
    <p>coming soon!</p>
</section>
 
<section id="Radio">
  <p> </p>
<h1><center>Radio</center></h1>
<p> </p>
<IMG SRC="giphy.gif">
  <p>coming soon!</p>
</section>
<section id="Contact">
  <p> </p>
<h1><center>Contact</center></h1>
</section>
</body>
```

And the other one seems to be an empty file with just the `head` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
```

If we go to your github pages deployment and we inspect the source code, we can see that what you are deploying is `index.html`, which has no content and is just an HTML `head`:

[image]

So you're technically deploying fine, it's just that you're deploying something that you probably don't intend to. So, either combine the HTML files, or delete the one that has no content.

Answer (score 0):

when deployed the server automatically server you the index.html as soon as you go to the website link

*https://bbravoo.github.io/bbravoo.github.io-/*

and your index.html has no body in it this is why it shows an empty page
but if you go to

*https://bbravoo.github.io/bbravoo.github.io-/site*

you will see your site.html page which has the code in it

I recommend learning how the web works and how servers respond to clients
it will help you a lot